# Using Spring JPA Projection with JHipster

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, jhipster

I'm having some difficulties to use [Spring Data JPA Projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) in a project generated with [JHipster](https://www.jhipster.tech/) version 4.14.5.

I'm following Spring's orientation on how to make projections using JPA respositories, however I'm not having any success. The repo give me `null` values when I try to use projections.

Since I'm not a big *connoisseur* of JHipster's pipes, I hope somebody out there may help me out.
My Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "research")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Research implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "answer", nullable = false)
private String answer;

@OneToOne(optional = false)
@NotNull
@JoinColumn()
private Question question;
// getters and setters
```

Entity projection:

```
public interface ResearchSimple {
    Long getId();
    String getAnswer();
}
```

Entity's repo:

```
@Repository
public interface ResearchRepository
extends JpaRepository<Research, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT r FROM Research r)
    List<ResearchSimple> findAllAsSimple();
}
```

Test Results

```
List<ResearchSimple> result = repo.findAllAsSimple();
assertEquals(result.size, dbSize); // OK
ResearchSimple simple = result.get(0);
assertNotNull(simple); // OK
assertNotNull(simple.getId); // FAIL!
assertNotNull(simple.getAnswer); // FAIL!
```

Debugging the value obtained in `simple` I've noticed that the projection was made, but I can't access it's value. Notice that the class `br.com.pixinside.projection.ResearchSimple` is present in `simple`'s `advised`.

```
org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory: 2 interfaces    [br.com.pixinside.projection.ResearchSimple, org.springframework.data.projection.TargetAware]; 3 advisors [org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor: pointcut [Pointcut.TRUE]; advice [org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor@1d62a0b], org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor: pointcut [Pointcut.TRUE]; advice [org.springframework.data.projection.ProxyProjectionFactory$TargetAwareMethodInterceptor@3b89f41a], org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor: pointcut [Pointcut.TRUE]; advice [org.springframework.data.projection.ProjectingMethodInterceptor@198453c9]]; targetSource [SingletonTargetSource for target object [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap@319267ad]]; proxyTargetClass=false; optimize=false; opaque=true; exposeProxy=false; frozen=false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you wanna use projection with manually queries , then you should use aliases that matches field names in your projection interface. `@Query("SELECT r.id as id, r.answer as answer FROM Research r)`
Or just skip @Query, and use `List<ResearchSimple> findAllSimplifiedBy();`